# Is Hyper-V something that has to come with the edition of Windows, or is it installed on top?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I'm trying to get Windows Server 2008 x64 with Hyper-V in my machine.

Do I need to get an edition of Windows that has Hyper-V?
Or can I install windows without Hyper-V and then install "Hyper-V" as a separate product?

(I want the regular Windows with a GUI, not the "core" variant)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to get the edition WITH hyper-v or that Role is unavailable.  There is no way to upgrade to a version with hyper-v- a reinstall must be performed ([Why is there a 32-bit Windows Server 2008 option “without Hyper-V”?](http://blogs.technet.com/migreene/archive/2008/02/29/2947021.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. My earlier test confirms that you can't upgrade. That article is very informative, so i'm giving you the accepted answer, in case someone has this doubt in the future

Answer (score 1):

Unless you installed 2008 from the "without HyperV" media, you just add it as a role (and enable the VT feature in the BIOS, my most often forgotten step...) after 2008 is installed.

The only other option of which I'm aware is a core-like command-line-only standalone product that you can download to install HyperV with no GUI.

Comment: I did install from the "without HyperV", I can't add it on top of that? Do I need to get a DVD that doesn't have the "without Hyper-V"?
(The role isn't there in my current installation)

Comment: Ouch, I don't believe it's possible to install it from that installation.  Unless someone has something lovely to post, I'm afraid you're stuck with a reinstall.

Comment: I can say with certainty that Hyper-V is not included and cannot be added to an install of Windows installed from the "without Hyper-V" media.  You will need to reinstall from a W2K8 install DVD without that designation (doesnt' matter if you are installing Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter)

Answer (score 0):

Does [this link](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-server-2008/hyper-v-install-enable-on-windows-server-2008-64-bit/) help you at all or does it stop at a particular point?

I missed that you had the role missing from the list before...I'm not sure but [this link](http://www.petri.co.il/installing-hyper-v-on-windows-server-2008-server-core.htm) might have the tools to add the role; it sounds like that adding this to "core" installs also adds the role, so it *might* work for you. If the alternative is a reinstall I guess it might not hurt to try it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you said you didn't have the role option in the installation...

Comment: Yes, I found that link after asking the question...
When I try to install the KB update, it said something to the effect of "This update doesn't apply to your system".